# Issue with manifest/appcache files

Tags: caching, manifest, html5-appcache

I'm looking to declare an offline file that I can use for an iPad site. I believe I must be missing something in the setup as it doesn't seem to work correctly as I understand it. Here is what I have...

**index page:**

`<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" manifest="/cache.appcache">`

**.htaccess**

`AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>`

**cache.appcache**

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
/index.php
/img/img.jpg
/img/img@2x.jpg
/inc/script.php
/inc/styles.php

NETWORK:
# All URLs that start with the following lines
# are whitelisted.

FALLBACK:
```

Here are the steps I go through:

1. I navigate to the page and confirm that there are no errors and that
   the url to the cache.appcache along with the items inside it are
   linked correctly.
2. I navigate through the sites pages to confirm everything is
   functioning as expected. No errors seen.
3. I turn off the Ethernet.
4. I am able to move through pages I previously setup, however, if I
   hit refresh the pages all break and I can't get back to the site.

I may be misunderstanding how this is supposed to work for "offline" mode, but this seems incorrect to me.